# cannot telnet out to port 25 anywhere... (no iptables)?

Tags: centos, networking

I just started setting up a new VPS, using CentOS 6.8 (Final) minimal install.

Problem: Try to connect outward to anywhere on port 25, I get "No route to host". I am my own hosting company, expanding by putting VPS servers everywhere - this one however is not allowing outbound port 25. The data center is owned by GoDaddy - they have tested from outside the host (Plesk) and all works. Just from my VPS I canned connect out. My DNS is setup for email authentication, etc. problem is lower-level, I cannot get a SYN packet to them to receive the SYN_ACK. Normally, I would say iptables, fail2ban or he new firewall daemon on CentOS 7 - none are installed... thus the ps dump below...

I have verified resolve.conf, I installed bind-utils, and nslookup type=MX, gmail.com ... take the result (priority 5) - try to telnet to the gmail server on port 25, "No route to host".

iptables -F

try again, "No route to host".

Here is a ps dump, is there something else running that could block outbound port 25? (I checked with GoDaddy (it's in their data center), from the Plesk console outward - 25 works)... so it's like I am running a firewall on the OS blocking outbound.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  19236  1268 ?        Ss   Jul21   0:01 init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul21   0:00 [kthreadd/158086]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul21   0:00  \_ [khelper/158086]
root       147  0.0  0.0  10648   328 ?        S<s  Jul21   0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root       529  0.0  0.1 183948  4900 ?        Sl   Jul21   0:38 /sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5
ldap       567  0.0  0.0 2703668 3352 ?        Ssl  Jul21   1:48 /usr/sbin/slapd -h  ldap:/// ldapi:/// -u ldap -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf
root       587  0.0  0.0  66240   592 ?        Ss   Jul21   0:09 /usr/sbin/sshd
root     24716  0.0  0.1 100496  4600 ?        Ss   Jul30   0:00  \_ sshd: root@pts/1
root     24721  0.0  0.0 108312  1904 pts/1    Ss+  Jul30   0:00  |   \_ -bash
root     22629  0.0  0.1 100636  4960 ?        Ss   Jul31   0:01  \_ sshd: root@pts/0
root     22631  0.0  0.0 108312  1960 pts/0    Ss   Jul31   0:00      \_ -bash
root       309  0.0  0.0 110200  1080 pts/0    R+   07:45   0:00          \_ ps -auxf
root       311  0.0  0.0 105452   920 pts/0    S+   07:45   0:00          \_ less
root       598  0.0  0.0  21720   752 ?        Ss   Jul21   0:00 xinetd -stayalive -pidfile /var/run/xinetd.pid
clam       611  0.0 12.4 1062436 523540 ?      Ssl  Jul21   2:26 clamd
root       649  0.0  0.0 108176  1312 ?        S    Jul21   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --basedir=/usr --user=mysql
mysql      765  0.0  0.6 1235412 27720 ?       Sl   Jul21   7:21  \_ /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/fido.pwnz.org.err --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
root       793  0.0  0.0  19640  1132 ?        Ss   Jul21   0:21 /usr/sbin/dovecot
vmail      799  0.0  0.0  44956  1976 ?        S    Jul21   0:00  \_ dovecot/lmtp -L
vmail      800  0.0  0.0  44956  2544 ?        S    Jul21   0:00  \_ dovecot/lmtp -L
vmail      801  0.0  0.0  44956  2544 ?        S    Jul21   0:00  \_ dovecot/lmtp -L
vmail      802  0.0  0.0  44956  2548 ?        S    Jul21   0:00  \_ dovecot/lmtp -L
vmail      803  0.0  0.0  44956  1976 ?        S    Jul21   0:00  \_ dovecot/lmtp -L
dovecot    804  0.0  0.0  13092  1156 ?        S    Jul21   0:09  \_ dovecot/anvil
root       805  0.0  0.0  13224  1272 ?        S    Jul21   0:06  \_ dovecot/log
root       807  0.0  0.0  20500  2444 ?        S    Jul21   0:22  \_ dovecot/config
dovenull 18670  0.0  0.0  42164  3556 ?        S    Jul29   0:00  \_ dovecot/imap-login
vmail    18676  0.0  0.0  58120  3964 ?        S    Jul29   0:02  \_ dovecot/imap
dovenull  2293  0.0  0.0  42176  3564 ?        S    Jul30   0:00  \_ dovecot/imap-login
vmail     2296  0.0  0.1  58920  4540 ?        S    Jul30   0:01  \_ dovecot/imap
dovenull 16139  0.0  0.0  42176  3556 ?        S    Jul31   0:00  \_ dovecot/imap-login
vmail    16147  0.0  0.1  58512  4364 ?        S    Jul31   0:00  \_ dovecot/imap
dovenull 17198  0.0  0.0  42164  3556 ?        S    Jul31   0:00  \_ dovecot/imap-login
vmail    17200  0.0  0.0  58120  3972 ?        S    Jul31   0:00  \_ dovecot/imap
dovenull 26961  0.0  0.0  42164  3568 ?        S    Jul31   0:00  \_ dovecot/imap-login
vmail    26963  0.0  0.0  58284  4044 ?        S    Jul31   0:00  \_ dovecot/imap
dovenull 27066  0.0  0.0  42164  3572 ?        S    Jul31   0:00  \_ dovecot/imap-login
vmail    27069  0.0  0.0  58220  4184 ?        S    Jul31   0:00  \_ dovecot/imap
dovenull 28666  0.0  0.0  42164  3584 ?        S    Jul31   0:00  \_ dovecot/imap-login
vmail    28667  0.0  0.1  58356  4256 ?        S    Jul31   0:00  \_ dovecot/imap
dovenull 32595  0.0  0.0  42164  3556 ?        S    07:20   0:00  \_ dovecot/imap-login
vmail    32596  0.0  0.0  58164  4160 ?        S    07:20   0:00  \_ dovecot/imap
dovecot  32733  0.0  0.1 100408  4708 ?        S    07:41   0:00  \_ dovecot/auth
dovenull 32754  0.0  0.0  42164  3564 ?        S    07:41   0:00  \_ dovecot/imap-login
vmail    32755  0.0  0.0  58044  3776 ?        S    07:42   0:00  \_ dovecot/imap
dovecot    307  0.0  0.0  88896  3908 ?        S    07:44   0:00  \_ dovecot/dict
root       923  0.0  0.0  85536  1992 ?        Ss   Jul21   0:49 /usr/libexec/postfix/master -w
postfix    925  0.0  0.0  85848  3668 ?        S    Jul21   0:04  \_ qmgr -l -t unix -u
postfix   2190  0.0  0.0  85668  3552 ?        S    Jul21   0:06  \_ tlsmgr -l -t unix -u
postfix  32649  0.0  0.0  85652  3464 ?        S    07:27   0:00  \_ pickup -l -t unix -u
postfix  32723  0.0  0.0  85784  3840 ?        S    07:38   0:00  \_ proxymap -t unix -u
postfix  32724  0.0  0.0  85644  3468 ?        S    07:38   0:00  \_ anvil -l -t unix -u
postfix  32725  0.0  0.0  85660  3556 ?        S    07:38   0:00  \_ trivial-rewrite -n rewrite -t unix -u
postfix  32743  0.0  0.1  88688  5924 ?        S    07:41   0:00  \_ smtpd -n submission -t inet -u -o stress= -o syslog_name=postfix/submission -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026
postfix  32762  0.0  0.1  85936  4252 ?        Ss   07:42   0:00  \_ postscreen -l -n smtp -t inet -u
postfix  32763  0.0  0.0  85644  3568 ?        S    07:42   0:00  \_ dnsblog -z -t unix -u
postfix  32764  0.0  0.0  85644  3568 ?        S    07:42   0:00  \_ dnsblog -z -t unix -u
postfix  32765  0.0  0.1  88688  5964 ?        S    07:42   0:00  \_ smtpd -t pass -u -o stress=
postfix    300  0.0  0.0  85804  3700 ?        S    07:44   0:00  \_ cleanup -z -t unix -u
postfix    301  0.0  0.1  86188  4640 ?        S    07:44   0:00  \_ smtp -n smtp-amavis -t unix -u -o syslog_name=postfix/amavis -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200 -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes -o disable_dns_lookups=yes -o max_use=20
postfix    304  0.0  0.0  86108  3932 ?        S    07:44   0:00  \_ smtpd -n 127.0.0.1:10025 -t inet -u -o syslog_name=postfix/10025 -o content_filter= -o mynetworks_style=host -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8 -o local_recipient_maps= -o relay_recipient_maps= -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes -o smtp_tls_security_level=none -o smtpd_tls_security_level=none -o smtpd_restriction_classes= -o smtpd_delay_reject=no -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject -o smtpd_helo_restrictions= -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions= -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0 -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001 -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000 -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0 -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0 -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_address_mappings
postfix    305  0.0  0.0  85700  3620 ?        S    07:44   0:00  \_ pipe -n dovecot -t unix flags=DRh user=vmail vmail argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${domain} -m ${extension}
root       950  0.0  0.0 116876  1036 ?        Ss   Jul21   0:01 crond
iredapd   1055  0.0  0.3 318304 14944 ?        S    Jul21   0:20 python /opt/iredapd/iredapd.py
root      1061  0.0  0.0   4068   600 tty1     Ss+  Jul21   0:00 /sbin/mingetty console
root      1062  0.0  0.0   4068   516 tty2     Ss+  Jul21   0:00 /sbin/mingetty tty2
amavis    6265  0.0  1.8 343604 76744 ?        Ss   Jul22   0:11 /usr/sbin/amavisd (master)
amavis    1275  0.0  2.3 356780 100036 ?       S    Jul30   0:20  \_ /usr/sbin/amavisd (ch19-avail)
amavis   23292  0.0  2.4 361492 104432 ?       S    Jul31   0:29  \_ /usr/sbin/amavisd (ch11-avail)
amavis   27916  0.0  2.2 352008 94828 ?        S    Jul31   0:12  \_ /usr/sbin/amavisd (ch8-avail)
amavis   30355  0.0  2.1 349316 92128 ?        S    01:56   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/amavisd (ch4-avail)
amavis   32402  0.1  2.2 349852 92560 ?        S    06:59   0:04  \_ /usr/sbin/amavisd (ch4-avail)
root     23349  0.0  0.4 442344 17064 ?        Ss   Jul31   0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd
2001     23351  0.0  0.2 618000 11848 ?        Sl   Jul31   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   27257  0.0  0.5 545068 24824 ?        S    Jul31   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   30277  0.0  0.3 445148 16768 ?        S    01:41   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   30658  0.0  0.7 549236 30892 ?        S    02:37   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   32215  0.0  0.3 445816 15672 ?        S    06:27   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   32696  0.0  0.2 444056 12528 ?        S    07:34   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
```

Comment: https://www.godaddy.com/help/find-your-email-relay-server-122?

Comment: Many ISPs will block inbound AND outbound access to port 25.  This could be your problem.

Comment: You can edit your posts. If you need to merge accounts see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: You can try `tcptraceroute -n smtp.server.com 25` and see where exactly you are being denied access to the server.

Answer (score 0):

It's standard anti-spam procedure to prevent an end-user server from accessing SMTP port (25) anywhere on the planet. If you want to send out e-mails, use your hosting company's own mail relay.